# Adrduino IDE doesn't show port for connected ESP32 module

Tags: serial, usb, esp32, mac-os

When I go to select port there's no port for the connected ESP32 module. I am using Mac OS Mojave, mac mini. 
The port I find is [image]

Comment: maybe the reason is that the ESP32 module is not connected

Comment: Or maybe it uses a USB to UART chip that needs drivers installing, and you haven't installed them.

Comment: @jsotola it's connected for sure, it lights up and works with my windows.

Comment: @Majenko this is also my suspect. how do i know which driver and where to find and install them ?

Comment: Read the number on the chip. CH350G?

Comment: I see ESP32-WROOM-32D...

Comment: this one infact [https://www.amazon.fr/SeeKool-ESP-32S-d%C3%A9veloppement-Bluetooth-Ultra-Low/dp/B07DPP3BGZ/ref=sr_1_4?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=esp32&qid=1586468528&sr=8-4]

Comment: It's the number on the little black square chip you need. CP2102 or something is it?

Comment: It is written AMS1117, 3.3 XJS88

Comment: No, I said square, not rectangular.

Comment: oh hha unfortunately there's nothing written on it, totally black!

Comment: but we are in luck, from amazon listing i see it's CP2102!

Comment: @Majenko so what should i install? thanks

Comment: No idea, I'm not a mac user, and the way OS X is going I can see a lot of people jumping ship from OS X to something that they can work in.

Comment: @Majenko what you mean, what's wrong with OS X ?

Comment: Well, already in Catalina lots of things are failing to work (no 32-bit, increased obnoxious security, etc). And in the near future loads of drivers (kexts) will fail to work at all. My guess is that, at least for a while, the CH340G drivers will cease to work, and then be an even bigger pain to get going. Bybye cheap arduino clones on the Mac...

Comment: yes I have tried with some drivers like CH340G from other post solution but didn't work